# A constraint satisfaction problem on matrix sum involving symmetric group

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, matrices, asymptotics, symmetric-groups

Given $n\in\Bbb N$ what is the smallest with $m>n$ we need such that there is a non-negative $\epsilon<1$ and $\Phi_i,\Psi_j\in\Bbb C^{m\times m}$ at every $i,j\in[n]$ ($[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$) such that $$\sum_{\mathcal F_n\subseteq ([n]\rightarrow[n])\backslash S_n}\Big|\sum_{\substack{\mu\in\mathcal F_n}} Tr\big(\sum_{i=1}^n\Phi_i\Psi_{\mu(i)}\big)\Big|<\epsilon \cdot Tr\big(\sum_{i=1}^n\Phi_i\Psi_{\sigma(i)}\big)$$ for all $\sigma\in S_n$ where $([n]\rightarrow[n])$ is set of all functions from $[n]$ to $[n]$?